# Xamarin.Forms implement AndHud and BTProgressHud

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

Can anyone point me to a Xamarin.forms sample that utilises AndHud for Android and BTProgressHud for iOS (or anything similar)?

I know there is the ACR-Xamarin-Forms example here https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms, but it is way too complicated and completely over my head.

Surely there is a more simple easy to understand implementation, but if not some sort of guidance on how to get started on implementing it (for a C# and Xamarin newbie)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I've done it for iOS.  All you should need to do for Android is create an implementation of IHud that using AndHud instead of BTProgressHud.

First, create an interface in the shared project

```
public interface IHud
{
    void Show();
    void Show(string message);
    void Dismiss();
}
```

Next, in the iOS project, create an implementation of IHud using BTProgressHud component:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Hud))]
namespace project.iOS
{
    public class Hud : IHud
    {
        public Hud ()
        {
        }

        public void Show() {
            BTProgressHUD.Show ();
        }

        public void Show(string message) {
            BTProgressHUD.Show (message);
        }

        public void Dismiss() {
            BTProgressHUD.Dismiss ();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, to utilize this from Forms code, just do

```
    var hud = DependencyService.Get<IHud> ();
    hud.Show ("Loading Vehicles");

    // tasks...

    hud.Dismiss ();
```

Comment: Thankyou Jason, just what I needed

Comment: I am new to Xamarin development.

Which files I have to add from BTProgressHUD to my project ??Please specify..

Comment: @Jason I implemented the BTProgressHUD like above and its working fine but at one place the progress doesn't show. The scenario is on Login i show up the progress and on success i show up the Landing page and in OnAppearing i call a method in ViewModel which calls webservice. In this scenario progressHUD doesn't show up. Can you help here? I am trying to create a sample to showcase the same, will post once done.

Comment: please post a new question, don't piggyback on questions that were closed over 3 YEARS AGO

Answer (score 1):

My answer, which is quite similar to @jason's can be found here:

[Loading Icon for layout screen Xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013321/loading-icon-for-layout-screen-xamarin-android/29159057#29159057)