# How to include component in Xamarin / Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to include component in  Xamarin.Forms?

Please suggest some component which supports dialog box, select pictures from library which is supported in Xamarin.Forms.

Because as per my knowledge, components can be added only to device specific project but not in common Forms project in Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks.

Comment: by saying component, do you mean third party controls?

Comment: Components that are provided from http://components.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** (ok) - Components :
as Jason stated, create an interface in the common library.
then create wrapper implementations within each device-specific project.
like each variation to the same interface using DependencyService
your common code will talk to the right instance of that interface, after it has been automatically injected.

**Option 2** (worst) - Components :
if you can, use a Shared Library for your common Forms code.
then use compiler directives (#if #endif ...) in your class to separate device-specific implementation and probably different namespaces as well.

**Option 3** (best) - Non-Components :
instead of using Xamarin Components, use NuGet in your PCL/SharedLib, and get the awesome [Acr.XamForms](https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms), it has a User Dialogs and a Camera/Gallery lib

Comment: for media picking, there's also [Xamarin.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile)

Comment: Is there any example code available for Acr.XamForms / Xamarin.Mobile nuget package?

Comment: here's a [Acr.XamForms Dialog sample](https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms/blob/master/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/UserDialogViewModel.cs) and 
[Acr.XamForms Photo picker sample](https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms/blob/master/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/PhotoViewModel.cs)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Forms Labs](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) with Video & Image pickers.

Answer (score 0):

Include the component in your device-specific project, then use the Xamarin Forms' [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to inject that device specific behavior into your common Forms project.

Comment: Could you please provide some example code for same with any components in Xamarin.Forms.?

Comment: this answer has a sample using the BTProgressHud component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865185/xamarin-forms-implement-andhud-and-btprogresshud/25899026#25899026